# WinRT 8.1 Asynchronous DataBinding not updating UI

Tags: c#, asynchronous, data-binding, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

My question is similar to some others that I have read, but I have not been able to find an answer to my specific issue.

**Note:**
I have read the following questions before asking:

[ListView Data Binding for Windows 8.1 Store Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005641/listview-data-binding-for-windows-8-1-store-apps)

[WinRT ViewModel DataBind to async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849213/winrt-viewmodel-databind-to-async-method)

That being said, I am creating a Windows 8.1 application that loads a text file asynchronously, and binds the data to a `ListBox`.  I am sure that the issue has something to do with non-UI threads are not able to update the UI, so even though my data source implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the UI is not being updated when the data is loaded.  Here is my `LoadPayees()` method:

```
public async void LoadPayees()
{
    try
    {
        var json = await FileService.ReadFromFile("folder", "payees.json");
        IList<Payee> payeesFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Payee>>(json);
        var payees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>(payeesFromJson);
        _payees = payees;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {     
        throw;
    }

    if (_payees == null)
    {
        _payees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>();
    }
}
```

`LoadPayees()` is called in the `OnNavigatedTo()` event of my page.  I can see via breakpoints that the method is being called, and the payees are being loaded into an `ObservableCollection<Payee>`.  `_payees` is a property, which calls `OnPropertyChanged()` when it is set.

My question is, is there a way to have the UI thread be updated after `LoadPayees()` is finished loading the data?  I also read somewhere that using a `Task` is no good for the UI as well.  My static method `FileService.ReadFromFile()` returns a `Task<string>`.

**Edit:**

Here is my method `ReadFromFile()` which also calls to `OpenFile()`:

```
public static async Task<string> ReadFromFile(string subFolderName, string fileName)
{
    SetupFolder();
    var file = await OpenFile(subFolderName, fileName);
    var fileContents = string.Empty;

    if (file != null)
    {
        fileContents = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    }

    return fileContents;
}

public static async Task<StorageFile> OpenFile(string subFolderName, string fileName)
{
    if (_currentFolder != null)
    {
        var folder = await _currentFolder.CreateFolderAsync(subFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        return await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Here is the code for the properties, `View`, and `OnNavigatedTo()` as requested.

-- properties of the ViewModel --

```
private ObservableCollection<Payee> _payees;
private Payee _currentPayee;

public PayeesViewModel()
{
    _currentPayee = new Payee();
    _payees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>();
}

public ObservableCollection<Payee> Payees
{
    get { return _payees; }
    set
    {
        _payees = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public Payee CurrentPayee
{
    get { return _currentPayee; }
    set
    {
        _currentPayee = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

-- view --

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            DataContext="{Binding Path=CurrentPayee}"
            Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid>
        <!-- snip unrelated Grid code -->
    </Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="PayeesListBox"
             Margin="50,0,50,0"
             Width="300"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Payees}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CompanyName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

-- code behind --

```
private PayeesViewModel _vm = new PayeesViewModel();

public PayeesPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this._navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this._navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    this._navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;

    DataContext = _vm;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    _vm.LoadPayees();
}
```

Comment: I am following a tutorial from PluralSight called "Windows 8 - From Design to Delivery with C# and XAML".  The lessons are all built on Windows 8, so the 8.1 specific changes are not reflected.

Comment: These code snippets look fine for me. Can you add the property, view and OnNavigatedTo code?

Comment: When the await returns, it returns to the thread context it was called no matter where the work is done, that's why you can actually update the UI elements after awaitable methods that are called and returned to the calling UI thread. The LoadPayees() is called to the UI thread so you should be OK. We need to see the XAML and that you set the DataContext of the page correctly so that data binding works properly.

Comment: I have added the properties, view, and OnNavigatedTo() code.  The Grid that I snipped out is just a few TextBlock/TextBoxes for entering data that is saved to the Payees.  That part works fine, just the loading that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set the `DataContext` twice.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            DataContext="{Binding Path=CurrentPayee}"
            Grid.Row="1">
```

and

```
DataContext = _vm;
```

`ListBox` is a child from the outer `StackPanel` with DataContext CurrentPayee. On CurrentPayee you don't have Payees. You should not set DataContext multiple times.

Btw. change your code like following:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    await _vm.LoadPayees();
}

public async Task LoadPayees()
{
    try
    {
        var json = await FileService.ReadFromFile("folder", "payees.json");
        IList<Payee> payeesFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Payee>>(json);
        var payees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>(payeesFromJson);
        _payees = payees;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {     
        throw;
    }

    if (_payees == null)
    {
        _payees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>();
    }
}
```

You should never write async void for methods except event handlers.

**Edit:**

Change the ObservableCollection in your ViewModel. You should not have a public setter for a list.

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Payee> _payees = new ObservableCollection<Payee>();

public ObservableCollection<Payee> Payees
{
    get { return _payees; }
}
```

Than loop and add the items to the collection. Now, the view is notified.

```
foreach (var item in payeesFromJson)
{
    Payees.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: I removed the DataContext from the StackPanel and left it in the code-behind.  Made the changes you suggested so OnNavigatedTo() is async, but still not getting anything displaying.  LoadPayees is definitely populating the ObservableCollection, but I must still have something wrong with my binding.

Comment: I'm struggling to find another mistake. Can you upload your project somewhere?

Comment: I uploaded it to: http://www.absoluteparallax.com/stackoverflow/MyMoney.zip

I found also, the DataContext was being set at the Page level from the template:     DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

I removed that, but still the same result.

Comment: If you have any issues with saving the data, I had copied the code from `WriteToFile` to the `Save_Click` event handler, so that it would prompt me for the initial location to save the payees.json.

Comment: I am at work now, I will give that a shot when I get home. So the `ObservableCollection` doesn't notify the view even though it calls `OnPropertyChanged()` in the setter?

Comment: The OnPropertyChanged does notify the view that the collection object has been changed but in what you really are interested are the collection item changes (add, remove).

Comment: Your edit did the trick.  I wish I could +2 your answer, thank you for your extra effort in helping me get this straightened out!